# Getting cx_Oracle with correct case using conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, cx-oracle, conda

I'm new to Python. I'm using the Anaconda 4.1.1 (Python 3.5.2) distribution on Ubuntu. I started working on a project that uses [`cx_Oracle`](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/). O could of course install `cx_Oracle` using `pip`.

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

But everyone seems to be saying that Anaconda's `conda` is a much better package manager, virtual environment manager, and dependency manager that `pip` and `virtualenv` put together. I'd prefer to just use `conda` for managing everything.

So I made a `requirements.txt` file (some of my teammates will still be using `pip` and `virtualenv`) with the following line. (I want to support Python 3.5, so I need `cx_Oracle` 5.2.1, the current latest.)

```
cx_Oracle==5.2.1
```

Then I tell `conda` to create a virtual environment `foobar`:

```
conda create -n foobar --file requirements.txt
```

This fails; unfortunately `cx_Oracle` 5.2.1 is not yet in the Continuum conda repository (even though half the year has passed since it was released). However there are several channels (e.g. `mgckind`) purporting to supply version 5.2.1. There's just one problem: all the channels are supplying `cx_oracle` and not `cx_Oracle` (note the case difference). So this won't work:

```
conda create -n foobar -c mgckind --file requirements.txt
```

Even if I specify a channel as in the example above, and even though `requirements.txt` clearly says `cx_Oracle`, `conda` brings down `cx_oracle` with a lowercase `o`. Because Python module imports are apparently case sensitive, all my tests fail because they can't find `cx_Oracle` with an uppercase `O`.

Am I missing something simple here because I'm new to Python? Or is Anaconda really both behind the times and incompatible with `cx_Oracle`, meaning I'll have to use `pip install` and bring it down from PyPI?

If there is really a case difference, is this situation common on Conda vs PiPY? Is it a Conda policy to name things only in lowercase? How do others deal with the discrepancy?

Comment: Can you actually import the module at all? If so, have you tried changing `import cx_Oracle` to `import cx_oracle as cx_Oracle`?

Comment: I have not tried changing the code. Obviously that's a last resort, but it sidesteps the issue. My colleagues are using pip, as I mentioned---will the code break if I change it but then they download `cx_Oracle` using `pip`?

Comment: use exception handling: 
`try: 
    import cx_Oracle
except ImportError:
    import cx_oracle as cx_Oracle`

Comment: You're only changing the top of the file.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the central issue. I've added a new paragraph to the question; see what you think.

Comment: I feel like there is not much you can do about the fact that you're getting a lowercase module name for `cx_Oracle`. That's handled by the package management system you are using. If you're intent on using a certain package management system, then you will have to deal with the quirks that come with it by tweaking your scripts accordingly.

Comment: It's not conda that's behind the times, it's cx_Oracle. Mixed-case package names are [un-Pythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).

Comment: Perhaps, but is the solution to force everything to lowercase in Continuum Conda? This suddenly breaks a program depending on whether it pulls its dependencies from PyPI or Conda!! (It makes absolutely no sense to me that package imports should be case sensitive, but that according to [PEP 426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#name) package lookups should be case insensitive). Maybe you could expound on all this in a separate answer so that I can assign the bounty. :)

Comment: While I appreciate feedback, all the comments here assumed that what I described actually was a problem. It turns out that the package case didn't affect the module case at all, and the problem lay elsewhere---that's why I was asking for some real-world experience in case I had missed something; it turns out I had. See separate answer. No need for me to do a `try`/`except` when importing after all. See the explanation in my separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the lowercase package name on Continuum's conda repository. In fact I was missing something. I had created a new virtual environment as I mentioned in the question:

```
conda create -n foobar --file requirements.txt
```

The requirements file contained `cx_Oracle==5.2.1`, which I also mentioned. But what I did *not* mention is that I then tested the program using `nosetests`, and the `requirements.txt` file did *not* include `nose`! This means that the unit tests were being run by the default Anaconda installation of `nose`, which had no knowledge of `cx_Oracle`, which was not installed into the main Anaconda installation. (The virtual environment, because of dependency issues, had pulled down Python 3.4, while the Anaconda installation was using Python 3.5.)

In any case, the issue was that I inadvertently was using `nose` from the default installation of Anaconda, not from my virtual environment. The `cx_oracle` installed into my virtual environment, as kalefranz pointed out, will requires `import cx_Oracle` regardless of the case of its package name.

As soon as I installed `nose` into my virtual environment, running `nosetests` worked because it picked up the `cx_oracle` installation.

In summary the following seems to be the package/module case situation in the Python world:

- Python module imports are case-sensitive.
- Package names are case-insensitive.
- The new best-practices approach is to use all lowercase in package names.
- The PyPI repository retains case; the Continuum conda repository converts package names to lowercase.
- Regardless of whether one pulls a package from PyPI or Continuum conda, and regardless of which package case is used to retrieve them, the module name and its corresponding import statement in the code should retain the official case used by the library.

Answer (score 1):

The conda package name does not influence how your `import` the code in python.  Looking at the linux-64 package [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle/files) for example, while the package name is `cx_oracle` to conform to conda ecosystem standards, in python you *must* import that package with `import cx_Oracle`.  There are many examples of python packages on PyPI where the package name is different than how the package is imported in python code.  Just one of those python quirks I guess.

Comment: Well that's _very_ good news indeed. But I could almost swear that when I downloaded the latest version from the conda `mgckind` channel, the program couldn't find `cx_Oracle` when it imported it. Could it be that one of the channels is changing the import name? I'm new to Python, so I'll have to go back and check out the details to see what caused the problem. I hope you're right!

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much for tipping me off about this; you put me onto the right track about the real problem. It turns out that `nosetests` wasn't using the `cx_oracle` in my virtual environment; see my separate answer. The problem had nothing to do with package case at all.